# Why is Model.objects.filter returning an empty query?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am reading an article on django about making queries over [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#expressions-can-reference-transforms). I have the following snippets.

```
>>> Entry.objects.first().pub_date
datetime.date(2021, 8, 18)
>>> Entry.objects.first().mod_date
datetime.date(2021, 8, 18)
```

But if I try the following I get an empty queryset.

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=F('mod_date__year'))
```

Why is it not working. Is this a bug?

Comment: Could you add the logs for `Entry.objects.values()` after your filter? I was thinking the database was modified in between your commands. Maybe the `first()` refers to 2 different objects, or maybe it's just the same object but the `pub_date` and/or `mod_date` was changed in the background.

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: I am using sqlite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems django handles [`__year`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year) and the other `__` date extractions differently with annotate or F expressions,  compared to when you use it in a filter.

For example in Postgres, the query generated with `filter(pub_date__year=F('mod_date__year'))` is:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(\'year\' FROM pub_date") = ("mod_date")
```

which would result with an error. But if used with an integer year like `filter(pub_date__year=2021)`:

```
WHERE "pub_date" BETWEEN 2021-01-01 AND 2021-12-31'
```

**USING EXTRACT**:

To solve this, try to use [`Extract`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#extract) to generate the correct filter:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Extract


Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=Extract('mod_date', 'year'))
```

Which will generate this query:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(\'year\' FROM "pub_date") = (EXTRACT(\'year\' FROM "mod_date"))'
```